# background-image never shows up

Tags: css, background-image, bootstrap-4

Following a course on bootstrap and once again I'm having issues with background-image: url(../img/home.jpg) no-repeat;

It's not showing up. When I hover over the reference in brackets, it locates the image, but never pushes it to the live demo.

The code looks like this:

```css
#home-section {
  background-image: url(../img/home.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  min-height: 700px;
}
```

home-section is correctly attributed to be an id in the html header as well. I even did quotes, and it still located the file. Like I said, when I hover over the image in brackets, it can find the image and display it. But when I launch it to the live server, nothing happens. Getting incredibly frustrating. Could I have an extension that could be preventing it from showing properly?

Comment: Does `#home-section` have content inside that would give it a width? Are there any child elements that have a background applied?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue is with the relative URL to your image:

```
url(../img/home.jpg)
```

the ../ implies that your img directory is outside of your webroot. If you use Chrome, you can check this by opening Developer Tools (Ctrl+Shift+I) and switching to the Network tab. Watch for any requests in red - these are missing files.

You should also right click the page and use "inspect" to examine the html. Hover over your div and this will highlight it on the page, so you can see if it's where you expect it to be, and the size you expect it to be.

Comment: I have no requests in red when switching to the network tab. And when I hover over the div, the size is set height I put it to (700 px). My files are setup like this: index.html, and then I have folders of: css, fonts, img, js, scss. In the .scss file, I have the: background-image: url(../img/home.jpg). Like I said, when I hover over the reference in brackets, I get the small preview image showing that it seems the image. I just don't see it in the live browser local version?

Comment: In the chrome dev tools it has an entire line through the background-image and the yellow error says: "invalid property value". What does that mean?

Comment: Ok I fixed it by just removing the background-image and changing it to just background. But now the image is too low for lg screens. Is there anyway to change it so the picture is centered better for lg and xl screens on bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

If your local server of your Brackets editor displays the image correctly but your remote/live server doesn't, then there can only be one conclusion:

You don't have the same stuff on your live server as you have on your local machine.

Comment: The local server doesn't display it properly. When I hover over the image in the SCSS file, I can see the small preview of the image. Meaning it's been found in the entire project, but it won't display on the local live version. Not the webroot version.

Comment: SCSS file? Do you really mean SCSS file? If yes, that needs to be compiled into a css file. Nothing in your SCSS file will ever get to the browser unless you have a setup that does the compiling into css.

Comment: Your browser can only understand css. Not scss.

Comment: In the chrome dev tools it has an entire line through the background-image and the yellow error says: "invalid property value". What does that mean?

Comment: Mate, you need to post the code for the entire thing. Otherwise, it's all gonna be guesswork.

Comment: Ok I fixed it by just removing the background-image and changing it to just background. But now the image is too low for lg screens. Is there anyway to change it so the picture is centered better for lg and xl screens on bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you input a path to your image. What you should do instead is copy the image and place it in your working directory/folder, so the image can be found. That is most likely the case in which the image isn't displaying. Also, make sure that your file name is placed in quotes